# Instantiating an Object as a service in ASP.net Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, asp.net-core-webapi

Very inexperienced with Asp.Net, and I have a class that I want to be able to instantiate and use across some controllers, and I'm not really sure how to get arguments to my constructor.

I have a data type that I would like to use as a service called `Watcher` which has a constructor signature of `Watcher(string _path, bool _DeletionPolicy = false)` this provides a path to watch files, and sets the default deletion policy. (False is do nothing after expiration, a file "expires" after 90 days.)

I understand that I need to register the service with MVC in `ConfigureServices()`, but how would I go about instantiating those two (or one required) parameter?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

in brief you will have to do something like this:

Write your Watcher class that implements IWatcher interface:

```
public class Watcher : IWatcher
{
    private readonly string _path;
    private readonly bool _deletionPolicy;

    public Watcher(string path, bool deletionPolicy = false)
    {
        _path = path;
        _deletionPolicy = deletionPolicy;
    }
}
```

then in ConfigureServices method in Startup.cs register IWatcher to the Watcher class like this:

```
services.AddTransient<IWatcher>(w => new Watcher("some path", deletionPolicy));
```

Finall, in every controller where you need the Watcher class, use the IWatcher interface in a constructor. 
When you add the IWatcher to a controller constructor, the dependency injection will instantiate the Watcher as you have defined it in a ConfigureServices method. 
After that it will inject it in constructor and will assign it to a private variable.
Then you can use it within controller in a methods where needed.

```
public class SomeController : Controller
{
    private readonly IWatcher _watcher;

    public SomeController(IWatcher watcher)
    {
        _watcher = watcher;
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Use the factory delegate when adding the service

For example

```
services.AddTransient<Watcher>(sp => new Watcher("some path here", otherVariable));
```

From there when using the service as a dependency,

either via constructor injection

```
private readonly Watcher watcher;

//ctor
public MyController(Watcher watcher) {
    this.watcher = watcher;
    //...
}
```

or directly in an action

```
public IActionResult MyAction(int arg, [FromServices]Watcher watcher) {

}
```

the container will use that delegate when activating the class for injection.

Comment: where would the constructor go in an auto generated controller? Does there need to be anything in the body of the ctor?

Comment: You would need to update the controller to accept the dependency or you have the option to inject it directly into the action.